# Laravel: Additional Login Conditions not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I'm doing a Laravel authentication. I don't know if it is important to clarify that I'm using the `Auth::routes`. 
I added an `active` field to my users model. But even when is not active, I'm able to log in.

This is my user model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
use Laratrust\Traits\LaratrustUserTrait;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Auth;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    use LaratrustUserTrait;
    use HasApiTokens;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'active'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'active' => 'boolean',
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

}
```

Then, as the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#authenticating-users) specifies under the "Specifying Additional Conditions" section, I added inside my `LoginController.php` the custom validation with the extra parameter to the attempt function.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    /**
     * Handle an authentication attempt.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function authenticate(Request $request)
    {
        $email = $request->input('email');
        $password = $request->input('password');

        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'active' => 1])) {
            return redirect()->intended($redirectTo);
        }
    }

}
```

What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: what about creating a middle-ware that will be applicable to login route? You should check email-verified middleware you need something like that.

Comment: Is not if they validate their email or not. Is a variable that an administrator can assign to another user.

Comment: This is not about email verification, this about one column in table.

Comment: According to laravel documentation `Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'active' => 1])` will create query. So why do we need to check separately for active users.

Comment: change "authenticate" function name with " login"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important to clarify where to put the code of the Laravel documentation.
In order to make it work, you need to import `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` at the top of your `LoginController.php` file.

Then, you have to override the **credentials** function.

```
/**
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
 */
protected function credentials(Request $request) {
    $email = $request->input('email');
    $password = $request->input('password');
    return ['email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'active' => 1];
}
```

After doing this, the expected results were obtained.

Comment: he his not need credentials function  , he provide manually this.

Comment: How can we add NOT and OR condition in the login auth query? Kindly suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of override authenticate() method, override credentials method in your LoginController.

```
/**
 * Get the needed authorization credentials from the request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return array
 */
protected function credentials(Request $request)
{
    //return $request->only($this->username(), 'password');
    return ['email' => $request->{$this->username()}, 'password' => $request->password, 'active' => 1];
}
```

Comment: he his not need credentials function  , he provide manually this.

Comment: How can we add NOT and OR condition in the login auth query? Kindly suggest. Thanks.